IntelliJ Idea Ultimate пометил мой проект не рабочим
На главной рабочей ветке - prod, Intellij Idea пометил мой проект не рабочим, будто бы тестовый. А на других тестовых ветках все нормально. Как я могу это исправить?


Закрыть проект в IDE, а также саму IDE. В корне проекта удалить папку .idea и попробовать заново открыть проект в Intellij.
